# How to check if a character present in a column using R

Tags: r, dataframe

Below dataframe has both string and character,

[image: Input]

I need to detect a particular character(Here its L or H) in column 'Data'and display the same in new column.

My sample output should be

[image: Output]

Comment: Please share your sample data as copy/pasteable R syntax, e.g. `dput(your_data[1:4, ])` to make a copy/pasteable version of the first 4 rows. It's very hard to test a solution on a picture of data.

Comment: Also, you've asked quite a few questions, but only Accepted a single answer. I'd suggest going back to some of your old questions and accepting answers that worked--it's a nice way to keep the site tidy (so people know when questions are resolved) and to thank the answerers.

Comment: Here's a start, though not exactly the output you present (which is, btw, inconsistent with the text of your question): `cbind(dat, lapply(setNames(nm=c("C","L")), function(z) grepl(paste0("\\b",z,"\\b"), dat$Data)))`

Comment: or perhaps better `cbind(dat, lapply(setNames(nm=c("C","L")), function(z) ifelse(grepl(paste0("\\b",z,"\\b"), dat$Data),z,NA)))`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to the example data would be to use `grepl()` along with an `ifelse()`:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(S.No = 1:4,
                Data = c("Climate is Cool",
                         "Climate is C at Carg / Desert",
                         "Longest / river is Nile",
                         "L is for Las Vegas"))
```

To scan for the patterns that would isolate the single letter of interest, you could use `\\b`. Combining this with an `ielse()` to create the new column:

```
df$C <- ifelse(grepl("\\bC\\b", df$Data), "C",NA)
df$L <- ifelse(grepl("\\bL\\b", df$Data), "L",NA)
```

Output:

```
# S.No                          Data    C    L
# 1    1               Climate is Cool <NA> <NA>
# 2    2 Climate is C at Carg / Desert    C <NA>
# 3    3       Longest / river is Nile <NA> <NA>
# 4    4            L is for Las Vegas <NA>    L
```

Comment: Great! As Gregor Thomas said, if there are no better solutions consider accepting this as an answer. Not required but it helps clean up the site a bit to close out the questions and helps other users know what works and what doesn't. Happy coding!